# Is there a way to perform a do-while?

Tags: matlab, loops, do-while

I'm planning to use a `do-while` loop in MATLAB.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 28):

```
while(true)

%code

    if condition==false
        break; 
    end 
end
```

Comment: I assume that this gives a similar functionality. However it is not exectly a do while loop. Still, it is no big deal I guess.

Comment: So is it the case that Matlab has no formal do while construct?

Comment: `condition==false` is more clearly and succinctly written as `~condition`. This notation makes it clear that we're negating the condition.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option in MATLAB (closer to a `do-while` syntax):

```
do = true;
while(do || condition)
    do = false;
    % things to do...
end
```

Comment: Be careful with this. If you use `continue` before setting `do = false`, then `condition` will be ignored. I would make `do = false` the first line of the while loop.

Comment: @PaulWintz you are right. I have edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

At least, [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/The-do_002duntil-Statement.html) has `do-until`.
This example creates a variable `fib` that contains the first ten elements of the Fibonacci sequence.

```
fib = ones (1, 10);
i = 2;
do
  i++;
  fib (i) = fib (i-1) + fib (i-2);
until (i == 10)
```

Of course, you must invert your abortion condition compared to `do-while`.

Answer (score -1):

MATLAB does not have a do-while construct (nor a do-until construct, in MATLAB the condition is always at the top of the loop). But you can always easily rewrite a do-while construct to a while-do construct.

For example, say you have a loop that iterates a computation until convergence. It is written as a do-while construct as follows:

```matlab
result = 0
do
   new_result = ...
   difference = abs(new_result - result)
   result = new_result
while difference > tol
```

You can write exactly the same thing with a while-do loop as follows:

```matlab
result = 0
difference = Inf
while difference > tol
   new_result = ...
   difference = abs(new_result - result)
   result = new_result
end
```

The only extra thing we needed to do was initialize `difference` to a value that guarantees that the loop runs at least once.

This is similar to [EHB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38971219/7328782) in that they also converted the do-while construct into a while-do construct. But in general it is not necessary to create a separate sentinel variable to do so.

Comment: Of course, a do-while loop is not necessary, but in many cases it is convenient, hence the OP's question (and the presence of do-while loops in most languages). In some cases, using a while instead of a do-while requires code duplication. Telling people to simply not try to use do-while is not helpful.

Comment: @PaulWintz do-while doesn't exist in MATLAB, I'm not telling people to not try to use it, I'm showing people how to encode the same logic with the available tools in the cleanest possible way.

Comment: Sure, and a while loop works fine for the example you gave, but in more complicated examples, a do-while loop allows us to avoid duplication, in which case the other answers are preferable.

Comment: @PaulWintz No, it doesn’t. Give me your more complex example and I’ll show you.