# Do While Loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop

I want to use a do while loop in Matlab:

I am currently using this code, but I don't think that I am doing it right:

```
flag2=true;

while (flag2)

    % (I write the program here)

    for abc = 1:3
        if abs(error(abc)) < errorTreshold
            flag2=false;
            break
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: what error do you get? there is at least one `end` missing at the end.

Comment: the loop ends immediately...i think I have an error in the for loop :S

Comment: maybe the if-condition is always true and therefore it always aborts. Leave out the `flag2=false;break` and use `disp(abs(error(abc)) < errorTreshold)` to see whether that'S the reason

Comment: Related and possibly duplicate: [Matlab - Is there a way to perform a do-while?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920206/matlab-is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-do-while)

Comment: Mostly, you need not use the break statement.

Answer (score 0):

You must do:

```
if abs(error(abc)) > errorTreshold
```

> instead of "<"

or see if you can do (removing the 'if'):

```
while abs(error(abc))>errorTreshold
```

Comment: is there maybe a method like in java to use do something while condition...as i want the program to at least do something once...and like that i would eliminate the flag

Comment: @user3074215:As far as I know there isn't.The use of flags as you wrote is the appropriate method.If you check it you can see that the first condition is always executed (under 'while').Your error was just the ">" symbol.